# How to retrieve image in database to webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am building a social network site using asp.net c# , And i am having a problem with retrieving image, when i upload an image to the database it name will be changed and it save on real path i mentioned.And also i want to say it saves in database as name of its .but i cannot link it to the webform.

html code

```
<asp:Image ID="Pro_pic" runat="server" Height="233px" ImageUrl="~/Profile/Image/Default.png" style="margin-left: 8px; margin-top: 13px" Width="187px" />
```

This is code behind file

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{






        string db = "";
        db = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(db);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [UserData] WHERE Email = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() + "'";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {

            Pro_pic.ImageUrl = @"C:\Users\Supun\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\MeetYou\ProfilePic\"+dr["ProfilePic"];

        }

        con.Close();







}
```

And this is sql code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserData] (
[YourName]    VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Email]       VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Password]    VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Gender]      VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Birthday]    VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[AboutMe]     VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Country]     VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[ID]          NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[ProfilePic ] NVARCHAR (500)       NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_UserData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Email] ASC)
```

);

Could someboday tell me how to get this image URL properly???

I think error on this

```
Pro_pic.ImageUrl = @"C:\Users\Supun\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\MeetYou\ProfilePic\"+dr["ProfilePic"];
```

Comment: It looks like the `ProfilePic` is the name of the profile photo, and that you have all the profile photos in the same folder? What is the problem then? Do you get an exception? Or what happens?

Comment: yes all photos in same folder but those have different names , photo is not loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the folder with the images as a subfolder of your application. Having it in an location outside of your application directly will cause such access issues. If you put the folder (let's name it "Images") in your application location, then you can assign the ImageUrl property to be "~/Images/" + your file name.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow certain guidelines while working with images in a web environment especially ASP.NET and MVC.

1. Try not to store an image using byte [] stream and then reconstructing it from the database using a query which is both slow and unoptimised.
2. Standard way is create a /Images folder in root directory where you put your images.
3. Write a class Library:

   public class QueryClass
   {
       string img_url;
       SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("//CONNECTION_STRING");
       SqlCommand cmd;
       SqlDataReader reader;

   ```
   public string getImageUrl(){
       cmd=new SqlCommand("select * from UserData where WHERE Email = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() + "'",con);
       reader=cmd.ExecuteReader();
       while(reader.read()){
           img_url=reader[8].ToString();
           break;
       }
       return img_url;
   }
   ```
4. Store the url (or Uri) to the image ,i.e, Image Path example: /Images/tree.png and bind it to a image control.
5. Store the Url string as a database entity and retrieve it through a query.
   Example: `SELECT img FROM Users WHERE username=@uname`
6. Run the query and store the url in a string say `string img_url=QueryClass.getImageUrl();`
7. Finally use `Pro_pic.ImageUrl= "/Images/"+img_url;`